# How can I test a ros package version from python script

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, rosversion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears there's a mechanism to fetch package version via ROS, available in CLI

> e.g. rosversion nano_light

> 0.0.0

where 0.0.0 is saved in the ROS package XML

is there an API to get this data from rospy?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/369994/how-can-i-test-a-ros-package-version-from-python-script/) by [nirge](https://answers.ros.org/users/67591/nirge/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here's one way to do it in Python, using `rospkg`:

```
import rospkg

r = rospkg.RosPack()
m = r.get_manifest('my_package')
print(m.version)

# Output: '1.3.0'
```

---

Originally posted by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) with karma: 1421 on 2021-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2